# Enum/Dictionary-Like Tool in C?

Tags: c

I'm reading over a solution to a problem in K&R's chapter 7 posted [here](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K&R2_solutions%3aChapter_7%3aExercise_1). Basically, the program will convert the standard input into lowercase or uppercase depending on the name of the program ("upper" or "lower"). It seems to store the names of the conversion functions in some kind of dictionary, like so:

```
int (*convcase[2])(int) = {toupper, tolower};
```

and later access these functions depending on whether the name of the program started with a u or an l:

```
if(argc > 0)
  {
    if(toupper((unsigned char)argv[0][0]) == 'U')
    {
      func = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      func = 1;
    }

    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
      ch = (*convcase[func])((unsigned char)ch);
      putchar(ch);
    }
  }
```

I understand what that code block is doing, but I've never seen anything like the initial declaration of convcase. It seems like some kind of weird combination of a macro, an enum, and an array. Could anyone explain (1) why convcase is a pointer; (2) what's with the (int) cast after its name; (3) what exactly toupper and tolower are within that declaration, because they're not char *s; and (4) when/why to use this kind of setup. Is it just a quick macro-like tool to save some space when you have multiple possible function calls?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Comment: http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28%2Aconvcase%5B2%5D%29%28int%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `convcase` is an array of two function pointers; It's not a pointer. An array expression will be implicitly converted to a pointer when it is used in a place where a pointer is expected.
2. That's not a cast. It's specifying that the functions accept an `int` argument, as the `toupper` and `tolower` functions do.
3. `convcase` is initialised with the function pointers `toupper` and `tolower`.
4. I presume this question is regarding function pointers. Use function pointers when you wish for the abstraction of function pointers. I'd suggest that this example is an unnecessary use of function pointers. The ability to change `convcase[0]` or `convcase[1]` to Spanish or Japanese, depending upon user input would more likely warrant the use of function pointers in this case. Additionally, function pointers could be used in arguments to provide additional abstraction. For example, the [qsort](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html) function is able to sort arrays of any type because of it's usage of function pointers for a *comparer* of objects. Here's an example that sorts `int` input using the `int_compare` function as the *comparer*.

```
#define nelem(array) (sizeof (array) / sizeof *(array))

int int_compare(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    int x = *(int *)p1, y = *(int *)p2;
    return (x > y) - (y > x);
}

int main(void) {
    int value[16];
    for (size_t x = 0; x < nelem(value); x++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &value[x]) != 1) {
            break;
        }
    }

    qsort(value, sizeof *value, x, int_compare);
    return 0;
}
```